# cauchy test for to prove a series divergent

Tags: divergent-series, cauchy-sequences

Use the cauchy test to show summation of $ 1/(n* ln ( n)) $ is diviergent.
I have done this much shown in image.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just integrate and put logx = t and solve improper integral .You will find it diverge